# How to add a fixed button in the footer in material ui dialog?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I'm trying to create a dialog pop up for my react js app, when user clicks on button, dialog opens up. I have form with input fields in that dialog, after user fills out all inputs he can submit info by clicking "submit" button at the bottom of the dialog pop up. The problem is that I don't know how to stick submit button  to the footer so even if there are 15+ inputs, user doesn't have to scroll all the way down to see "submit" button. I know that material ui has DialogActions for this purpose, but because dialog is in parent component, I don't have access to DialogActions from child. My code:

```
App.js (parent)

import React, { useState } from "react";

import Info from "./Info";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { DialogTitle } from "@material-ui/core";

import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";

import { DialogActions } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button onClick={handleClickOpen}>Click me to open dialog</button>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
        maxWidth="md"
        setMaxWidth="md"
        fullWidth={true}
      >
        <dialogContent>
          <dialogTitle>
            {" "}
            <div>
              <h4>Fill out the form</h4>
            </div>
          </dialogTitle>
          <DialogContentText>
            <Info />
          </DialogContentText>
        </dialogContent>
        {/* <DialogActions>
          <button id="responsive-dialog-title" onClick={handleClose}>
            {" "}
            Submit{" "}
          </button>
        </DialogActions> */}
      </Dialog>{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

and Info.js (child) :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function Info() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(username);
    console.log(password);
    console.log(address);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          width: "350px",
          padding: "20px"
        }}
      >
        <label> Username</label>
        <input
          value={username}
          onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
        />
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          width: "350px",
          padding: "20px"
        }}
      >
        <label> Password</label>
        <input
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          type="password"
        />
      </div>

      <button> Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-sun-bp0om?file=/src/Info.js:0-1123)

Is there any way to make that "submit" button in Info.js displayed as DialogActions/ fixed to bottom? Any help and suggestion are greatly aprreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `position: fixed` property to achieve that. Your code would look like this:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        width: "350px",
        padding: "20px"
      }}
    >
      <label> Username</label>
      <input
        value={username}
        onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
        type="text"
      />
    </div>
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        width: "350px",
        padding: "20px"
      }}
    >
      <label> Password</label>
      <input
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        type="password"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style={{ position: "fixed" }}>
    <button> Submit</button>
    <button> Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The scroll that the dialog has by default also had to be removed

```
<Dialog
    open={open}
    aria-labelledby="responsive-dialog-title"
    maxWidth="md"
    setMaxWidth="md"
    fullWidth={true}
  >
    <div style={{ overflow: "hidden", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
      <dialogTitle>
        {" "}
        <div>
          <h4>Fill out the form</h4>
        </div>
      </dialogTitle>
      <Info />
    </div>
  </Dialog>
```

This works, but the best thing to do is call the submit function from the parent, or the submit function exists in the parent and the inputs can be filled with context or a simple state

Comment: hi, it doesn't work, when I add 6+ inputs buttons still are getting pushed down, and if I add more inputs buttons are not visisble.

Comment: @nika Also Edited! also in your codesandbox